# I want to count how many results have 'failed' or 'passed' and organise them by date

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have a table with three columns: ID, DATE, and RESULT

```
ID  | DATE       | RESULT   
id1 | 2017-06-20 | fail
id2 | 2017-06-20 | pass
id3 | 2017-06-20 | pass
id4 | 2017-06-19 | pass
id5 | 2017-06-19 | pass
id6 | 2017-06-18 | fail
```

I want to count the no. of IDs with a "pass" or a "fail" and organise them by date.

Expected result: Three columns: DATE, PASS, FAIL

```
DATE       | PASS_COUNT | FAIL_COUNT
2017-06-20 | 2          | 1
2017-06-19 | 2          | 0
2017-06-18 | 0          | 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(A:C, 
 "select B,count(B) 
  where B is not null 
  group by B 
  pivot C 
  order by B desc", 1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This was very useful, @player0. Thank you very much!